# onClick event not firing in React redux ToDoList application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, dom-events

The onClick event is not firing at all.I am able to add todos and toggle todos but when i click on Completed todos or NotCompleted todos nothing happens.Here is the complete code for the class. There is an add to do which adds the todos.then there is a toggle to do which strikes or unstrikes a todo.the problem that I am having is with the CompletedTodos and NotCompletedTodos list items.

```
   class TodoList extends Component {
    render() {

console.log(this.props.todos)
return  (
  <div className='todo'>
  <form id="frm1">
        Add To Do: <input type="text" name="fname" id="todo" /><br></br>
        <input type="button" onClick={()=> this.props.actions.addTodo(document.getElementById("todo").value)} value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <div className="visible">
   <ul className=" visibility">
   <li onClick={ () => {

     return(<div> {this.props.todos.map(todo => {
       return (<p> {todo.text} </p>)
     })}</div>)
   }}>

      AllToDos


  </li>

   <li onClick={() => {
     return (<div> {this.props.todos.filter(todo => {
       if(todo.completed===true) {
         return (<p> {todo.text} </p>)
       }

     })}</div>)
      }}>

      CompletedToDos

   </li>

   <li onClick={() => {
     return ( <div> {this.props.todos.filter(todo => {
       if(todo.completed===false) {
         return (<p> {todo.text} </p>)
       }
     })}</div>)
      }}>

      NotCompletedToDos

   </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <ul className='todo__list'>
     {this.props.todos.map(t => (
       <li key={t.id} className='todo__item' onClick={() => this.props.actions.toggleTodo(t.id)}>
         <Todo todo={t} />
       </li>
     ))}
   </ul>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens because, onclick on `List` elements returns a DOM but nowhere you are displaying it.

You should do it like

```
class TodoList extends Component {
        state = {
            displayTodos: []
         }
        render() {

        console.log(this.props.todos)
        return  (
          <div className='todo'>
          <form id="frm1">
                Add To Do: <input type="text" name="fname" id="todo" /><br></br>
                <input type="button" onClick={()=> this.props.actions.addTodo(document.getElementById("todo").value)} value="Submit" />
          </form>
          <div className="visible">
           <ul className=" visibility">
           <li onClick={ () => {
             var todos = []
             todos = this.props.todos.map(todo => {
               return (<p> {todo.text} </p>)
             })
             this.setState({displayTodos: todos})
           }}>

              AllToDos


          </li>

           <li onClick={() => {
             var todos = [];
              this.props.todos.filter(todo => {
               if(todo.completed===true) {
                 todos.push(<p> {todo.text} </p>)
               }
              })
              this.setState({displayTodos: todos})
              }}>

              CompletedToDos

           </li>

           <li onClick={() => {
             var todos = []
             this.props.todos.filter(todo => {
               if(todo.completed===false) {
                 todos.push(<p> {todo.text} </p>)
               }
             })
             this.setState({displayTodos: todos})
              }}>

              NotCompletedToDos

           </li>

            </ul>
            <div>{this.state.displayTodos}</div>
          </div>
          <ul className='todo__list'>
             {this.props.todos.map(t => (
               <li key={t.id} className='todo__item' onClick={() => this.props.actions.toggleTodo(t.id)}>
                 <Todo todo={t} />
               </li>
             ))}
           </ul>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Also I would personally call a function `onClick` rather than do everyting inline to increase code `readability`

Answer (score 0):

sorry, But I don't know what's the target of click function,
it don't change the Component state or props, so this component will not render.

```
<li onClick={() => {
     return (<div> {this.props.todos.filter(todo => {
       if(todo.completed===true) {
         return (<p> {todo.text} </p>)
       }

     })}</div>)
      }}>

      CompletedToDos

   </li>

   <li onClick={() => {
     return ( <div> {this.props.todos.filter(todo => {
       if(todo.completed===false) {
         return (<p> {todo.text} </p>)
       }
     })}</div>)
      }}>

      NotCompletedToDos

   </li>
```

Comment: what i want to do is render everything that's inside of onClick whenever i click on the list item tags. How can I correct my mistake?

Comment: you can try to update the component state, such as `onClick={e => this.setState({complete: true or false})}` and when your render this list, you can change it like this:`
     {this.props.todos.filter(one => one.completed}).map(t => (
       <li key={t.id} className='todo__item' onClick={() => this.props.actions.toggleTodo(t.id)}>
         <Todo todo={t} />
       </li>
     ))}
 `

Comment: but i am using redux so doing this violates the philosophy of redux right?

Comment: if so, just add an action: filterList => (list, action) {return newList}, then render the newList

Comment: the problem is when i render the new list it updates the global state and then that creates problems further down the line.I just want to filter the state and keep the original state intact.I hope you get my point.