# onClick event is not firing(react redux todo list application)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, dom-events

My onClick events for all,completed and notcompleted are not firing when the corresponding li items are clicked. When I click on the li tags the corresponding functions are not called for some reason.I am unable to find the mistake here.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import {Component} from 'react'
import Todo from './Todo'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {addTodo,toggleTodo,select_1,select_2,select_3} from 
'../actions/index'
import {all} from './todosall'
import {completed} from './todoscomp'
import {notCompleted} from './todosnotcomp'

class TodoList extends Component {
  render() {

const alltodos=() =>{
  return (
    <div> <all todos={this.props.todos} /> </div>
  )
}

const completed=() =>{
  return (
    <div> <completed todos={this.props.todos} /> </div>
  )
}

const notCompleted=() =>{
  return (
    <div> <notCompleted todos={this.props.todos} /> </div>
  )
}

console.log(this.props.todos)
return  (
  <div className='todo'>
  <form id="frm1">
        Add To Do: <input type="text" name="fname" id="todo" /><br></br>
        <input type="button" onClick={()=> this.props.actions.addTodo(document.getElementById("todo").value)} value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <div className="visible">
   <ul className=" visibility">
   <li onClick={alltodos}>

      AllToDos

  </li>

  <li onClick= {completed}>

      CompletedToDos

   </li>
   <li onClick={notCompleted}>

      NotCompletedToDos

   </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <ul className='todo__list'>
     {this.props.todos.map(t => (
       <li key={t.id} className='todo__item' onClick={() => this.props.actions.toggleTodo(t.id)}>
         <Todo todo={t} />
       </li>
     ))}
   </ul>
  </div>
)
```

}
}

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
    todos: state.todos
 }
```

}

```
  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return {
  actions: 
    bindActionCreators({addTodo,toggleTodo,select_1,select_2,select_3}, 
     dispatch)

 }
```

}

```
 export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList);
```

Comment: did you check the log I think  this.props.actions.toggleTodo(t.id) will throw the error because when you used map at that time context of this should be a function of map

Comment: I am not getting any error in the console.It's just that the click event is not firing; nothing happens when i click on the list items.

Comment: <li key={t.id} className='todo__item' onClick={() => this.props.actions.toggleTodo(t.id)}>
         <Todo todo={t} />
       </li> in this code it may be possible your click will fire on <Todo /> component and your li didn't get onClick

Comment: So what's the solution for this?

Comment: rather putting onClick on li you have to put onClick event on element on <Todo /> Component

Comment: Todo component is working fine.The problem is with all,completed and notcompleted onClick events.I have edited the question too.

Comment: I think you're having a scoping issue. I believe you have to do <li onClick={this.completed}>. You have to put "this" before it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick event not firing in React redux ToDoList application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490501/onclick-event-not-firing-in-react-redux-todolist-application)